# Devise: Forget password flow when different from logged in user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I start forget password flow for user A.  I'm logged in as user B.

When I click on the password reset link for user A, I'm directed to root_url with user B still logged in.

Can I change the behavior so that I still go through password reset for user A?  Seems like Devise is auto directing to root even if user B is different from the requested user A password reset.

Comment: You would have override Devise::PasswordsController and log the user out. Whats actually happening is that the SessionsController detects that there is a user signed in and redirects.

Comment: This is because devise keeps sessions for each user. So I would recommend you to go to incognito and initiate reset password for user B from there.